# Wrap Datatables rows().every() with Typescript Generators

Tags: typescript, datatables, iterator, datatables-1.10

I want to wrap the rows().every function with typescript generators/iterator

This is my first approach

```
public * rowIterator1(): IterableIterator<DataTables.RowMethods> {

    var self = this.dataTable;
    this.dataTable.rows().every(function*(rowIdx) {
        console.log(rowIdx);
        let row = self.row(rowIdx);

        yield row;
    });

}
```

But the every() function is not stopping when yield row is called.

Next approach was with async generators

```
public async * rowIterator3() {

    yield await new Promise((res) => {
        var self = this;
        this.dataTable.rows().every(function (rowIdx) {
            console.log(rowIdx);
            let row = self.dataTable.row(rowIdx);

            res(row);
        });

    });
}
```

Same problem, console.log says

> 0
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4

The function is not stopping when yield was called

In the end I would like to have something like this:

```
DtWrapper.rows((row: JQuery, index: number) => {
   do something
}
```

Well after fiddling several hours, this seems to work. Although using the iterator is not what i've expected.

```
public * getRows() {    

        let rowIndexes = this.dataTable.rows().indexes();
        let count = rowIndexes.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            let rowIndex = rowIndexes[i];
            let row = this.dataTable.row(rowIndex);
            yield $(row.node());
        }
    }

    public test() {


        let t = this.getRows(true);

        let a = t.next();
        a = t.next();
        a = t.next();
```

}

Comment: But the idea / algorithm of `every` is "take every element until the iterator is exhausted" . If you want to iterate one element at a time, use a `for (... of ...)` (or the iterator directly).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: I would like to wrap the datatables component in a Wrapper Class. This Wrapper should have an Iterator Function to iterate over table rows. The Iterator Function should only return the node (JQuery) and the index of the row, not the row Object itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed a solution that will work for me. (Thx @Pac0 for giving the right input)

```
function* func1() {
  yield 42;
  yield 2;
}

function* func2(param) {
    if (param)
    return;
  yield* func1();
}



for (var value of func2(true))
{
    console.log(value);
}
console.log("finished true");

for (var value of func2(false))
{
    console.log(value);
}
console.log("finished false");
```

Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qu9ksxpd/

Answer (score 1):

The iterator will effectively stop executing at each yield when you call it using `next()`.

The `every()` builtin JS will accept an iterator and try to exhaust it (calling `next()` until the iterator flag the iterator as done).

To consume an iterator (created by a generator function or not), the usual way is to use it in `for (... of ...)`. This will effectively get each element and treat it independently, calling `next()` appropriately at each iteration.

Comment: Thx, need to set "downlevelIteration": true, in tsconfig, now for of is working

Comment: Is is possible to build the generator that way, that a for (... of ...) loop will skip the loop because the generator has no values?

Comment: @DanielR if the generator generates no value and finished immediately, then the `for ... of` should behave as if you were iterating an empty array. Isn't that working out-of-the box ?

Comment: yes it does, but I have another generator which passes the generator through with yield*. But in some cases I need to return without passing through the generator

Comment: @DanielR I'd suggest writing another question for this specific need, with an explanation of what you are trying to achieve globally (including why do you think you need to "return without passing through the generator", which is quite unclear to me at the moment)

Comment: solved it by myself. Here is a fiddle of what I meant https://jsfiddle.net/qu9ksxpd/

Comment: @DanielR, great! It's an elegant solution to wrap in some kind of "sentinel generator" as you did. You can still write a specific question and answer it yourself, if you think this will benefit the community. Otherwise glad you made it work anyway.